# How to create a liferay project in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, liferay, liferay-6, netbeans-8

I am very new to **Netbeans** and **Liferay MVC Portlet**. I Have a requirement to **Create a Liferay + Spring MVC application**. I have tried my best by checking into the Official website of **Netbeans** and **Liferay**. I am very familiar with **Eclipse** and i was very much successfully in getting it started with the **Liferay SDK Plugin**. But i am trying to follow the steps which i did in **Eclipse** for **Netbeans** and i see myself going round alway. Please guide me to get this setup for me in **Netbeans**.

I have a **NetBeans version of 8.1 and Liferay version i am looking for is 6.2 Spring 4 and Maven**

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Unless you're coming with specific issues that you're facing, stackoverflow is not quite the right place for this type of question. Let us know what exactly you did, what problem you face - otherwise you risk this question being closed soon.

Comment: To Make the question simple. "How to Run Liferay + Spring MVC developed in NetBeans IDE

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans (currently) doesn't have support for Liferay projects. All you can do is generate the project from the outside, open it as a Web Project, work on it, then run **ant** from terminal. But that is nonesense if you are familiar with Eclipse, because Liferay is supported in it. Why would you change IDE then?